# Micronaut - Exception: manualy registered singleton by adding framework dependecy

Tags: java, maven, graphql, runtime-error, micronaut

I currently have an existing Micronaut server project that containing multiple endpoints. I'm considering incorporating an additional GraphQL endpoint and introducing management endpoints for a new feature. However, whenever I add one of these dependencies (micronaut-graphql or micronaut-management), the software fails to start and consistently generates the following error message:

```
←[36m13:12:08.804←[0;39m ←[1;30m[main]←[0;39m ←[1;31mERROR←[0;39m ←[35mio.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut←[0;39m - Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouter]

Message: Bean of type [class io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment] is a manually registered singleton that was registered with the context via BeanContext.registerBean(..) and cannot be created directly
Path Taken: NettyEmbeddedServer.buildDefaultServer(NettyHttpServerConfiguration configuration) --> new DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext,[RouteExecutor routeExecutor],MediaTypeCodecRegistry mediaTypeCodecRegistry,StaticResourceResolver staticResourceResolver,ThreadFactory nettyThreadFactory,HttpCompressionStrategy httpCompressionStrategy,EventLoopGroupFactory eventLoopGroupFactory,EventLoopGroupRegistry eventLoopGroupRegistry) --> new RouteExecutor([Router router],BeanContext beanContext,RequestArgumentSatisfier requestArgumentSatisfier,HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration,ErrorResponseProcessor errorResponseProcessor,ExecutorSelector executorSelector) --> new DefaultRouter([Collection builders])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouter]

Message: Bean of type [class io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment] is a manually registered singleton that was registered with the context via BeanContext.registerBean(..) and cannot be created directly
Path Taken: NettyEmbeddedServer.buildDefaultServer(NettyHttpServerConfiguration configuration) --> new DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext,[RouteExecutor routeExecutor],MediaTypeCodecRegistry mediaTypeCodecRegistry,StaticResourceResolver staticResourceResolver,ThreadFactory nettyThreadFactory,HttpCompressionStrategy httpCompressionStrategy,EventLoopGroupFactory eventLoopGroupFactory,EventLoopGroupRegistry eventLoopGroupRegistry) --> new RouteExecutor([Router router],BeanContext beanContext,RequestArgumentSatisfier requestArgumentSatisfier,HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration,ErrorResponseProcessor errorResponseProcessor,ExecutorSelector executorSelector) --> new DefaultRouter([Collection builders])
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2367)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2853)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:3511)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3457)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3427)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:1381)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:72)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBeansOfType(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2161)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeansOfTypeForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1437)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.$DefaultRouter$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.$RouteExecutor$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1599)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory$BuildDefaultServer0$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1680)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1655)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:878)
        at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:291)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:77)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:323)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:309)
        at demo.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Bean of type [class io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment] is a manually registered singleton that was registered with the context via BeanContext.registerBean(..) and cannot be created directly
        at io.micronaut.context.NoInjectionBeanDefinition.getConstructor(NoInjectionBeanDefinition.java:131)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2315)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
        at io.micronaut.management.endpoint.processors.$DeleteEndpointRouteBuilder$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        ... 68 common frames omitted
```

For reproducing the problem I created a small example project here (without having the dependencies and tests for /health and /graphql enabled here:

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/HPIMartin/MicronautDemo/tree/main)

If the dependencies are added the tests are green but if I build the jar file e.g. using the provided dockerfile the resulting jar is failing.